# Как разделить галереи?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!
На странице есть много мини-галерей картинок. При переключении картинок в одной галерее, одновременно и в других галереях картинки также переключаются. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно этого избежать, индивидуализируя каждую галерею?
И второй вопрос: активной картинке присваивается класс `.pp_window-img_miniatures_active`. Но когда она перестает быть активной, класс остается. Как его удалить?
Спасибо большое за помощь!

```js
$('.pp_window-img_miniatures').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
  $('.pp_window-img_visible_active').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
$(".pp_window-img_miniatures img").addClass(".pp_window-img_miniatures_active");
});
```

```css
.galery1,
.galery2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.pp_window-img_miniatures {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.pp_window-img_miniatures img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pp_window-img_miniatures_active {
  border: 2px solid brown;
}

.pp_window-img_visible {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="galery1">
  <div class="pp_window-img_miniatures">
    <img src="https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/0bfea04e1e1cd7c313b4f9b7f2925494?s=200&d=https%3A%2F%2Fs1.wp.com%2Fi%2Flogo%2Fwpcom-gray-white.png&r=G" alt="" />
    <img src="https://0.academia-photos.com/12563268/3584878/4206492/s200_sergio.tique.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://1.gravatar.com/blavatar/90ecd77fe2fd6b9356666ff0629aae9d?s=200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pp_window-img_visible">
    <img class="pp_window-img_visible_active" src="https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/0bfea04e1e1cd7c313b4f9b7f2925494?s=200&d=https%3A%2F%2Fs1.wp.com%2Fi%2Flogo%2Fwpcom-gray-white.png&r=G" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="galery2">
  <div class="pp_window-img_miniatures">
    <img src="http://www.youtoart.com/design_pic/smallpic/1212/s_17485.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://4put.ru/pictures/small/277/853429.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://ipadw.ru/ipad/thumb/1089-thumbs-greenflow.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pp_window-img_visible">
    <img class="pp_window-img_visible_active" src="http://www.youtoart.com/design_pic/smallpic/1212/s_17485.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо поправить JS код примерно на такой:

```
$('.pp_window-img_miniatures').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
$(this).parents('[class^="galery"]').find('.pp_window-img_miniatures_active').removeClass("pp_window-img_miniatures_active");   
$(this).parents('[class^="galery"]').find('.pp_window-img_visible_active').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
$(this).addClass("pp_window-img_miniatures_active");
});
```

Что исправлено:

- для выбранной картинки ищем родительский элемент galery* и удаляем у
  картинок класс pp_window-img_miniatures_active;
- ищем родительский элемент galery* и уже в пределах только этой галереи меняем src для большой
  картинки;
- в параметре для функции addClass не надо добавлять точку к имени класса.